# I am facing mapping user and profile in django

Tags: python, django

I am facing a problem with Django profile mapping with user.There is coming None in admin view

[image: my admin]

This is my models.py

```
    profile_of = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    session = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False )
    batch = models.IntegerField()  # batch = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    iit_program = models.CharField(blank=True, choices=IIT_PROGRAM, max_length=10)
    college = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    graduate_university = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Dhaka University')
    graduate_department = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Software Engineering')
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    is_current = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

This is my views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from .forms import UserProfile
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


    @login_required(login_url= '/accounts/login/')
    def userProfileview(request):
        
        form = UserProfile(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        

        context = {'form':form}

        return render(request,'userprofile.html', context)
```

This is my forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import Profile

    class UserProfile(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            fields = 
          ['iit_program','batch','session','graduate_university','graduate_department','photo']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the admin list view is the Model converted to a string, you can control how the model is converted with the **str** function, the return value of this function must be a string

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_of = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
         return self.profile_of.name
```